# What is meant by 'top-level directory' (app bundle context)?

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

In the Apple documentation there is mention of the 'top-level directory of an iOS application bundle'. I dont understand what is meant by 'top-level' here. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone installs your app, iOS creates a sandbox, basically a folder and dumps all you code/executable into that folder along with some data folders like Documents, Caches, etc... That way your app has access to only that folder in which the app is installed & all subfolders. So you cant access anything outside it. Like other apps, coz they are on different folder. So, top level would mean is the directory in which your app is installed, you can see it like 'root directory' for your app.